# I need two JTextFields that influence each other

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a JPanel with two JTextFields. If the user writes some text into textfield A the same text should appear in textfield B and vice versa.

How can that be implemented without getting an infinite loop.

So far I have the following which leds to a infinite loop.

```
        JTextField textFieldA;
        JTextField textFieldB;

        textFieldA.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {  
                Document doc = (Document)e.getDocument();
                String line = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());  
                textFieldB.setText(line);
            }
            textFieldB.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {  
                    Document doc = (Document)e.getDocument();
                    String line = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());  
                    textFieldA.setText(line);
                }
```

Comment: why don't you share the same document instance across the textFields?

Comment: could you elaborate please :)

Comment: ehh .. on what? cant think of anything which might be unclear in: use the same document in both fields :-)

Comment: @kleopatra, once again I don't know how I missed your comments. I guess I was too busy looking at the answers. I would have upvoted you if your response was posted as an answer :)

Comment: @camickr no problem, doesn't matter who gives the correct answer, as long as it _is_ given :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean to mark when you are propagating changes.

```
    JTextField textFieldA;
    JTextField textFieldB;
    boolean updating = false;

    textFieldA.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {  
            if(!updating) {
            updating = true;
            Document doc = (Document)e.getDocument();
            String line = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());  
            textFieldB.setText(line);
            updating = false;
            }
        }
    textFieldB.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {  
            if(!updating) {
            updating = true;
            Document doc = (Document)e.getDocument();
            String line = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());  
            textFieldA.setText(line);
            updating = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: that's it! and so easy but sometimes you just don't see it. thanks @all

Comment: not really optimal: flags are brittle plus such an approach doesn't scale (with number of documents) smoothly

Comment: @user836038 If you want the view to be the same then share the model, don't keep two of them. See my answer below.

Comment: The solution posted by @camickr is probably a lot better; you should use that one.

Answer (score 7):

Take advantage of MVC design and share the model:

```
textFieldB.setDocument(textFieldA.getDocument());
```

Comment: @trashgod, thanks for editing the code. Sometimes the fingers don't type what the brain is thinking :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to update `textFieldB` only if `textFieldA` [hasFocus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isFocusOwner%28%29) (and vice versa)

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it with a key listener on both Text fields, the keyPressed event then copys the triggered field to the other. greets

Comment: wrong answer - you _never_ (as in 99.99 %) use keyListeners in Swing application, with an even stronger _never_ (as in 99.9999999999%) in text components

Comment: @kleopatra I'll never do it again=) can you tell me why? I am involved in a few swing applications and would like to improve them =)

Comment: good plan - searching for "swing keylistener" should come up with a couple of explanations :-)